# Change bindingsource query to use varchar instead of nvarchar

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, datagridview

I use the following code that pulls a value from a datarow and uses that value to get the correct results from another table.  The problem I am running into is that the value from the datarow is a string that apparently is nvarchar and that is causing problems with sql.  It should be a varchar which is what it is in the table and when run in sql it is very fast as opposed to obnoxiously slow and times out in my application.  I know its a nvarchar based on the analyzer showing the N' before the value.

How can I change this to make sure the value of masteraccount is varchar when passed into the query?

```
   System.Data.DataRowView SelectedRowView;
    waterDataSet.WaterAccountsRow SelectedRow;

    SelectedRowView = (System.Data.DataRowView)waterAccountsBindingSource.Current;
    SelectedRow = (waterDataSet.WaterAccountsRow)SelectedRowView.Row;

    frmWater WaterForm = new frmWater(this);
    WaterForm.LoadWaterAcct(SelectedRow.MASTER_ACCOUNT, null);
    WaterForm.Show();
```

The rest of the code is here:

```
public void LoadWaterAcct(String Acct, String tableName)
{
    arTableAdapter1.FillByWaterAcct(waterDataSet1.AR, castAcct);
    demTableAdapter1.FillByMAcct(waterDataSet1.DEM, Acct);
}
```

The query that is created by FillByWaterAcct is as follows:

```
exec sp_executesql 
N'SELECT MASTER_ACCOUNT, ACCT_KEY, INST_KEY, CUST_KEY, WATER_ACCOUNT, BILL_CYCLE, DUE_DATE, PRIM_TYPE, WATER_CHG, WATER_SVC_CHG, SEWER_CHG, SEWER_SVC_CHG, PENALTY_AMT, LIEN_FEE, INVOICE_AMT, INDUSTRY_CHG, FIRE_CHG, STORM_WATER_CHG, MISC_AMT, CREDIT_AMT, TOTAL_AMT, DEBT_COL, DEBT_COL_STAGE, ACCT_BILL_STAT, DEBT_COL_DATE, PLAN_AMT, JUDGEMENT_DATE
    FROM            AR
    WHERE        (MASTER_ACCOUNT = @Acct)
    ORDER BY BILL_CYCLE',N'@Acct nvarchar(20)',@Acct=N'000764658'
```

What needs to change is this

```
@Acct nvarchar(20) to @Acct varchar(20)
```

How do I do that?  The query is created by c# when executed.

Comment: I dont know C# but simple cast in tsql would do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open YourDataSet.Designer.cs
2. Search for @Acct, you'll find something like SqlParameter("@Acct", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.nvachar. Change nvachar to varchar

Comment: Thank you so much!  This was terribly difficult to troubleshoot.  Silly nvarchar.